# Battery connector name

Tags: power, batteries, identification, connector, connect

I want to attach this battery to my PCB but I am unable to find out which male connector should I put on PCB to connect this battery? Since I will be using JLCPCB SMT assembly so it would be great if i get the part number of the male connector.

Here is the link:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BJ5QJ2GS?starsLeft=1&ref_=cm_sw_r_cso_cp_apin_dp_Y81FWDZ2CG3GRZ829PMS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BJ5QJ2GS)

Comment: I doubt this connector is proprietary. If you know the pitch and width of the pins, you could use a generic header connector based on that information.

Comment: looks like a Molex KK series, but can't be 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link says MTA-100 connector, which is a TE Connectivity series number (for the male half, though). As the '100' implies, it's a 2.54mm-pitch connector, and it looks to me like it has a retention rib (though the photo is pretty bad).

You may be able to find a compatible part (with a similar rib and polarization scheme) from another manufacturer that is stocked by your chosen PCBA house. There will be at least two options- vertical and right-angle.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. But, as far as I know, all MTA-100 connectors are IDC, while the picture in that ad shows a crimped connector.  I think the title of that ad may be technically incorrect.

Comment: @DavideAndrea It might be the mating connector, was my thought but it could just be wrong. There's significant differences in the position of the retention rib between makers. I'm not sure I'd be comfortable ordering a bunch of assembled boards without more information from the battery vendor and/or a part in hand.

Answer (score 2):

My [Identiconn connector identification utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification1.html?n=single_wall_conn_2p5) identifies it as a Single-wall connectors, ~2.5 mm.

It is made by many companies, including Molex: KK 254 (2.54 mm pitch).